# Read from serial port in Windows

Tags: c, windows, serial-port

I'm trying to read serial data from rs232. My rs232 is connected in comport COM11. I specified COM11 in my serial.h file. below is the code.

```
void port_open()
{
hSerial = 
CreateFile("COM11",GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,0,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
..
```

My main c code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "serial.h"
void main()
{
while(1)
    {
    port_open();
    printf("%s\n",port_read());
    }
}
```

After run the c code, im getting...

```
serial port does not exist
some other error occured. Inform user.
error getting state
error setting serial port state
error setting port state
error reading from input buffer


--------------------------------
Process exited after 0.4768 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I think my program cant able to find the comport. How to resolve this? Thanks

Comment: Please, provide full code of functions `port_open` and `port_read`

Comment: it doesn't make sense to call `port_open()` in an endless loop. If the rest of your code worked, you would soon run out of file handles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get access to serial ports with port number larger then 9 you should use

```
CreateFile("\\\\.\\COM11",GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,0,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
```

More info [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/115831/).